# custom font in LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, fonts, uistoryboard, launch-screen

I am modifying a LaunchScreen.storyboard file. I want to use custom font for labels inside it. My font is of type .fft. I cannot make IBOutlets to a View Controller because launch screens cannot be a subclass of UIViewController.

So how to use custom font in LaunchScreen.storyboard file?

Comment: You are referring to LaunchScreen.xib file, or Main.storyboard file? I get a LaunchScreen.xib file, and the custom fonts are not available at this point.

Comment: Subclass a view and load the fonts in the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use custom fonts on the Launch screen. Only standard system fonts.

System will automatically replace your custom font to system during runtime.